# Как правильно указать путь при get запросе?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

Есть 2 Schema MongoDB.

Для регистрации пользователей и их персональным списком задач, который ссылается на Todo:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const {Schema, Types, model} = mongoose;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    todos: [{ type: Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Todo' }]
})

export default model('User', userSchema);
```

И непосредственно сам список задач, который имеет своего User'a в поле owner:

```
        import mongoose from "mongoose";
    
    const {Schema, Types, model} = mongoose;
    
    const todoSchema = new Schema({
        owner: {type: Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
        title: {type: String, required: true},
        complete: false
    })

export default model('Todo', todoSchema);
```

Вопрос:

Как мне правильно запросить список задач пользователя, который уже прошел авторизацию по JWT Token'у при обращении к серверу?

Мой вариант выглядел вот так, но он не работает:

```
    import {Router} from "express";
    import Todo from '../models/todo.js'
    
    export const todoRouter = new Router();

    todoRouter.get('/', async (request, response) => {
    try {
        const {userId} = request.query;

        const todos = await new Todo.find({owner: userId});

        response.json(todos);

    } catch (error) {

        response.status(500).json({message: 'Ошибка при запросе списка задач', error});
        console.log(error);

    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const todos = await Todo.find({owner: userId});
```

Попробуйте не использовать new. New создаёт новое, а вы ничего не создаёте.
И ещё не совсем понятно, зачем вам в схеме пользователя todos, когда у вас и так у каждого todo есть поле пользователь.